# Microsoft objects, the Release() functions return value?

Tags: c++, com, pointers, directx, reference-counting

I'm curious because I couldn't find out about this on MSDN. I've found the `Release()` function is present in various COM objects which I'm obviously supposed to use for deleting pointers. But I'm not sure what does it return exactly? I used to think it would return the number of references which still exist to the object remaining, therefore something like:

```
while( pointer->Release() > 0 );
```

Would obviously release all references to that pointer?

Or am I not seeing something?

*note I'm talking about this from the concept of the `IDirect3DTexture9::Release()` function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your theory is true. COM memory management is based on reference counting. The `Release` method of `IUnknown` interface will decrement the reference count and return it. That function will not release *references*. It doesn't know who holds the reference. It just decrements the reference count until it reaches zero and then the object will be destructed. It's dangerous as others might still hold a reference to it that will become invalid after object's destruction.

Thus, you should only call `Release` for each `AddRef` you had previously called.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to what Mehrdad said, the return value of Release is intended for debugging purposes only.  Production code should just ignore it.

**Looping until Release() returns 0 is definitely a bug** - you should never release references you don't own.

Answer (score 6):

Release() would return the current reference count of the object. But you shouldn't do:

```
while( pointer->Release() > 0 );
```

This will make the reference count zero and destroy the object.

> In COM a simple thumb rule is every AddRef()
>   there should be corresponding
>   Release() (only one).

Normally Release() implementation would look like this:

```
int nCount = InterlockedDecrement(&this->m_cRef); //Decrement the ref count
if (nCount == 0) 
{
    delete this;
}
return nCount;
```