# Cleaning up directx, releasing com references properly

Tags: com, directx

I am just learning directx. One typically creates a directx device and several other COM interfaces through a functions calls such as

```
ID3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(.... ,& device, ...);
```

In all tutorial code I have seen, the com interfaces are released using something akin to

```
if (pointer_to_com_object) {
    pointer_to_com_object->Release(); 
    pointer_to_com_object = 0;
}
```

e.g. the following is taken from Tutorial07_2008 in the directx 11 tutorials from Microsoft.

```
if( g_pSamplerLinear ) g_pSamplerLinear->Release();
if( g_pTextureRV ) g_pTextureRV->Release();
if( g_pCBNeverChanges ) g_pCBNeverChanges->Release();
if( g_pCBChangeOnResize ) g_pCBChangeOnResize->Release();
if( g_pCBChangesEveryFrame ) g_pCBChangesEveryFrame->Release();
if( g_pVertexBuffer ) g_pVertexBuffer->Release();
if( g_pIndexBuffer ) g_pIndexBuffer->Release();
if( g_pVertexLayout ) g_pVertexLayout->Release();
if( g_pVertexShader ) g_pVertexShader->Release();
if( g_pPixelShader ) g_pPixelShader->Release();
if( g_pDepthStencil ) g_pDepthStencil->Release();
if( g_pDepthStencilView ) g_pDepthStencilView->Release();
if( g_pRenderTargetView ) g_pRenderTargetView->Release();
if( g_pSwapChain ) g_pSwapChain->Release();
if( g_pImmediateContext ) g_pImmediateContext->Release();
if( g_pd3dDevice ) g_pd3dDevice->Release();
```

As pointed out in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888673/microsoft-objects-the-release-functions-return-value) COM objects can have references to them you don't own.

So is the above a bad way to clean up directx or do directx COM objects never have references to them you didn't create?

I just ask because I keep seeing it done this way as I am learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COM objects are reference counted. When you call `Release()`, you are effectively decrementing the internal reference count. If another object still owns a reference, it will not get destroyed.

If some other part of the application end up having a new reference to a COM object, make sure you call `Release()` when you are done with it. Carefully read documentation of methods that return references to know if you have to call `Release()` or not. Usually you will have to.

For instance in [IDirect3DTexture9::GetSurfaceLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> Calling this method will increase the
>   internal reference count on the
>   IDirect3DSurface9 interface. Failure
>   to call IUnknown::Release when
>   finished using this IDirect3DSurface9
>   interface results in a memory leak.

Comment: Due to other objects owning references, you do need to take at least a bit of care to make sure you release them all. I like to make sure they're not bound anywhere, then release in reverse order of creation.